# Flutter - onTap doesn't work when i'm using InkWell

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hay every one,
i'm  building my new app, and everything worked fine
but sadly, the inkwell onTap doesn't work

```
body: groups.isEmpty
      ? Center(child: Text('No Students'))
      : GridView(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            childAspectRatio: 8.0 / 10.0,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
          ),
          children: [
            ...groups.map(
              (group) => Card(
                  elevation: 7,
                  child: Wrap(
                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset('assets/01.jpg'),
                      Text(group),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => ThirdPage())),
                      )
                    ],
                  )),
            )
          ],
        )
```

i have a felling that i'm putting the inkwell in the wrong position, but i don't know where to move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add widget as a child in inkwell, which you want to make tappable.

I hope it helps,

```
 groups.isEmpty
        ? Center(child: Text('No Students'))
        : GridView(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        childAspectRatio: 8.0 / 10.0,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      children: [
        ...groups.map(
              (group) => Card(
              elevation: 7,
              child: Wrap(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                children: <Widget>[
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ThirdPage())),
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset('assets/01.jpg'),
                      Text(group),
                    ],),
                  )

                ],
              )),
        )
      ],
    )
```